# Как склоняется "бонус-малус"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение

Как склоняется слово "бонус-малус"? По типу слова "счет-фактура" или нет?
Была уверена, что при склонении изменяются обе части слова "бонус-малус". Но в Викисловаре обнаружила, что склоняется только вторая часть. Почему так? Или Викисловарь ошибается?

Comment: А почему были уверены? В "счёте-фактуре" обе части - существительные, здесь - прилагательные без русского окончания. Это ближе к "форс-мажору" (там даже существительное не склоняется, ибо туманно для русского понимания). http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/63-rubric-93

Comment: "Бонус" - существительное. Уж точно не прилагательное.

Comment: Посмотрите в любом источнике, как переводится эта часть сочетания с латыни (в английском сочетании bonus track это тоже прилагательное - как и первое слово в сочетании compact disc). Вероятно, вам знакомы только "бонусы" в значении премиальных выплат.

Comment: Латынь и английский - одно. А в русском языке это существительное мужского рода.

Comment: БОНУС -а; м. [от лат. bonus — добрый, хороший].
1. Дополнительное вознаграждение; надбавка к выплате, премия.
2. Дополнительная скидка, предоставляемая продавцом в соответствии с условиями сделки.

Толковый словарь Кузнецова

Источник: https://gufo.me/search?term=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81#ixzz5FLqalLey

Comment: Да мало ли как это слово переведено с английского в других значениях? Там оно используется и как существительное (с артиклем), и как прилагательное (в переводе - бонусный, дополнительный, поощрительный) в составных понятиях. В латыни же существительное - bonum (хорошая вещь), а производное прилагательное - bonus (хороший). Наименование коэффициента составлено непосредственно из латинских прилагательных, а в русский перенесено транлитерацией сочетания, а не составлено из слов, ранее переведённых в других значениях.

Comment: Как это - "мало ли как переведено"? Я вам ссылку на толковый словарь дала, где сказано, что это существительное мужского рода. Прилагательное с этим корнем - "бонусный". Прилагательного "бонус" в русском языке нет.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь вписать составной частью в самостоятельное понятии слова, которые не имеют к нему смыслового отношения - считайте, что нет и этих существительных, исходите из этимологии.

Comment: Извините, но вы что-то странное говорите :) Слово "бонус" имеет самое прямое смысловое отношение к "бонус-малусу". Да и смысла исходить из этимологии не вижу. "Ресторан" по этимологии - тоже прилагательное, но в современном русском языке оно является исключительно существительным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак не склоняется, несклоняемое это слово, и параллели с другими сложными составными словами не работают.

Как Вы склоняете *кофе глясе,* или *макси-пальто,* или *интернет-кафе*? Вот так и с бонус-малус, которого нет в словарях, а Викисловарь находится в стадии перманентной доработки (пока).

---

> Далеко не всегда мы в состоянии с уверенностью сказать, обе ли части
>   слова склоняются. Наиболее верный способ ответить на этот вопрос —
>   обратиться к словарю. Правда, толковый словарь русского языка может
>   помочь не во всех случаях. Как уже ска­зано выше, большая часть этих
>   слов возникла относительно недавно и не успела попасть в словари.
>   Другие отмечены слова­рем, но им не посвящены отдельные статьи,
>   содержащие грам­матическую информацию.

**[источник](http://www.bibliotekar.ru/deloproizvodstvo-1/67.htm)**

---

См. также Письмовник на Грамоте.ру:

**[Как склонять составные существительные?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/63-rubric-93)**

Принципы (не)склоняемости изложены здесь:

[СЛОЖНЫЕ СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫЕ: СЛОЖЕНИЯ С ОПОРНЫМ КОМПОНЕНТОМ,
РАВНЫМ САМОСТОЯТЕЛЬНОМУ СЛОВУ](http://rusgram.narod.ru/550-587.html)

Примеры употребления:

1. [Во всех договорах, заключенных в течение одного года, для одного водителя должен быть указан единый класс бонус-малус.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%81)
2. [Президент РФ подписал закон об изменении применения коэффициента «бонус-малус» в ОСАГО.](http://www.insur-info.ru/news/2030/)

---

> **Бонус-малус** (в переводе с латинского «хороший-плохой», ср. англ. Bonus-Malus System, BMS) — система тарифных коэффициентов (не путать
>   со "скидками" - это не скидка!), обычно применяемая в страховом
>   бизнесе, которая изменяет размер страховой премии, которую платит
>   клиент (страхователь) страховщику в зависимости от его истории
>   страховых случаев.
>
> **Существуют и другие определения понятия бонус-малус:**
>
> Расчёт ставок страховой премии с учётом индивидуального опыта
>   вождения.
>
> Рейтинговая система, основанная на страховом опыте водителей.
>
> Система скидок за отсутствие страховых случаев.
>
> Рейтинговая система, основанная на прошлых заслугах водителей
>   (страхователей).

---

> Система бонус-малус является частью системы страхового тарифа и
>   базируется на актуарных расчётах.
>
> В России использование системы «бонус-малус» было заявлено с первых
>   дней введения в действие закона об ОСАГО, однако на практике
>   автоматизированная система, позволяющая учитывать аварийность водителя
>   (и по ОСАГО, и по каско), заработала только в 2013 году.
>
> Сам коэффициент бонус-малус начал действовать с 2003 года, хотя
>   автоматизированная информационная система была внедрена лишь в 2012
>   году.